# Dart with native mobile libraries calls

Tags: android, mobile, dart, stagexl

I'm considering to start project using Dart for the front-end development on the mobile platform. Basic idea is to use it for the UI  and develop platform specific solutions using native mobile sdks. So it leads me to the several questions:

- Can Dart with StageXL provide good performance for the UI components on the mobile platform ?
- Is it possible to make external functions call to the custom mobile framework ?

Sharing of any hands-on experience highly appreciated.

Comment: What is good performance?

Comment: as for me, good performance in UI related to user experience from it. so if it slow in rendering, or in touch response or etc, it means bad performance, i was able to experience this with PhoneGap sample for example. Custom mobile framework i see as my provider( that has to be developed for each platform) of camera functions that fully customize view and user experience from it usage.

Comment: Yeah, i guessed that, but its highly opinion based, and I depends a lot on what you want to do. I have no experience with PhoneGap/Cordova though.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by custom mobile frameworks? You can make calls to JavaScript if that is what you want. You can create Chrome-packaged-apps

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

- [Getting Started With Dart and Cordova From Scratch on iOS](http://financecoding.github.io/blog/2012/12/23/getting-started-with-dart-and-cordova-from-scratch-on-ios/)
- [Rikulo - Build Native Mobile Application](http://docs.rikulo.org/ui/latest/Getting_Started/Building_Native_Mobile_Application.html)

Comment: i don't want to use Cordova, i want to write my own library and then call it from Dart

Comment: Write your own library with what? (JavaScript, Java, ObjectivC) Dart doesn't run natively on mobile platforms yet. You have to build to JS and that runs only in the browser. So you will have to use something like PhoneGap/Cordova.

Comment: yes you right Dart compiles to java script. as it doesn't look like one to one mapping( Dart -> JavaScript ) it could be performance issues. Also can I avoid of using PhoneGap and directly call frameworks built on Java ( android ) or ObjectivC ( iphone ) for the mobile development ?

Comment: As far as I know you can't avoid PhoneGap. Benchmarks show that JS generated from Dart is as fast as code directly written in JS, sometimes even faster, but sometimes also slower but in overall very similar.